# Undefined method unexisting_url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I´m a newbie with Rails3 and I´ve got a strange problem. After searching in google and in StackOverflow for a while I decided to write down my question.

I have a `Competencia` and a `Partida` model. Competencia `has_many :partidas` and Partidas `belongs_to :competencia`.

I´m working with nested resources and my code looks like this:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :competencias do
  resources :partidas
end
```

**partidas_controller.rb**

```
class PartidasController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @competencia = Competencia.find(params[:competencia_id])
    @partida = @competencia.partidas.build
  end

  def create
    @competencia = Competencia.find(params[:competencia_id])
    @partida = @competencia.partidas.build(params[:partida])
    if @partida.save then #blabla end
  end
end
```

**views/partidas/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@competencia, @partida], :url => competencia_partidas_path(@competencia) do |f| %>
    <!--blabla-->
<% end %>
```

I know that it isn´t the right way to specify the url in the `form_for` helper (specially if I´m not using a custom action), but it was the only way I could work it out. When I wrote something like this: `<%= form_for [@competencia, @partida] do |f| %>` I´ve got this error:

```
Showing /Users/ks/rails/projects/chronos/app/views/partidas/new.html.erb where line #4 raised:

 undefined method `competencium_partidas_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000101718548>:0x00000101713728>
```

When I checked the routes (rake routes) everything seems to be fine.

```
competencia_partidas GET    /competencias/:competencia_id/partidas(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"partidas"}
                     POST   /competencias/:competencia_id/partidas(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"partidas"}
new_competencia_partida GET    /competencias/:competencia_id/partidas/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"partidas"}
```

Can someone explain me where the ***competencium*** name comes from?. What would be the correct approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Rails assumes english grammar rules for pluralization. You can read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html. You can customize the inflector or use English model names. I'm Italian and even when a project is meant only for Italian customer I prefer to use English names.

Answer (score 0):

Rails tries to singularize you model name. In your case, it thinks `competencia` is the plural of a latin word. To add an exception, put the following in `config/initializers/inflections.rb`:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections do |inflect|
  inflect.singular "competencia", "competencia"
end
```

Comment: Great! I will read more about inflectors and also will consider to switch my names into english. Thanks a lot for the quick answer. That was very usefull, I can research more info.